# Login Page error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
public partial class Account_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string UName = UserName.Text.Trim();
    string pwd = Password.Text;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, username, password, email FROM [Employee] WHERE username = '" + UName + "' and password = ' " + pwd + "' ";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session.Add("UserID", dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            Session.Add("UserName", dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
            Session.Add("Password", dt.Rows[0][2].ToString());
            Session.Add("Email", dt.Rows[0][3].ToString());
            if (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "admin")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Default.aspx", false);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/MemberPages/Default.aspx", false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid Username and Password";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me an error at UserName.Text and password.Text. It says that this doesn't exist in this context.

I don't know what's going wrong in this.

This same problem is also occuring with the registration page.

Comment: show your `Account_Login.aspx`

Comment: Please show your Markup portion where you added the Text boxes for UserName & Password

Answer (score 1):

There may be some issue in the designer file, that can cause this issue.

see: [The name 'xxx' does not exist in current context user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745856/the-name-xxx-does-not-exist-in-current-context-user-control)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a asp:Login control, then use the UserName and Password properties to retrieve the data.